# regexp parsing in matlab

Tags: regex, parsing, matlab

I have a cell array 3x1 like this:

```
name1 = text1
name2 = text2
name3 = text3
```

and I want to parse it into separate cells 1x2, for example name1 , text1. In future I want to treat text1 as a string to compare with other strings. How can I do it? I am trying with regexp and tokens, but I cannot write a proper formula for that, if someone can help me with it please, I will be grateful!

Comment: (\w+)\s=\s(\w+) <- Do you need something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
input = {'name1 = text1';
         'name2 = text2';
         'name3 = text3'};

result = cell(size(input, 1), 2);
for row = 1 : size(input, 1)
    tokens = regexp(input{row}, '(.*)=(.*)', 'tokens');
    if ~isempty(tokens)
        result(row, :) = tokens{1};
    end
end
```

produces the outcome

```
result = 
    'name1 '    ' text1'
    'name2 '    ' text2'
    'name3 '    ' text3'
```

Note that the whitespace around the equal sign is preserved. You can modify this behaviour by adjusting the regular expression, e.g. also try `'([^\s]+) *= *([^\s]+)'` giving

```
result = 
    'name1'    'text1'
    'name2'    'text2'
    'name3'    'text3'
```

**Edit:** Based on the comments by [user1578163](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578163/user1578163).

Matlab also supports less-greedy quantifiers. For example, the regexp `'(.*?) *= *(.*)'` (note the question mark after the asterisk) works, if the text contains spaces. It will transform

```
input = {'my name1 = any text1';
         'your name2 = more text2';
         'her name3 = another text3'};
```

into

```
result = 
    'my name1'      'any text1'    
    'your name2'    'more text2'   
    'her name3'     'another text3'
```

Comment: is there any way to remove white spaces in your first approach? second one is not working taht good, but first is ideal just need to remove the spaces to be able to compare strings.
and by the way, how do you recommend me to learn regular expressions and tokens? help on matlab is not enough in this manner, too few examples to understand how to combine all the 'signs'.

Comment: I know this expression will do the trick for a single string, but how to get into the cell of these strings? *regexprep(s,'[^\w'']','')*

Comment: @user1578163: Try `tokens{1}{1}` and `tokens{1}{2}` to get directly to the tokens. Why isn't the second regexp working as expected? What strings are failing?

Comment: @user1578163: I learned regular expressions from the SED tutorial http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.